# Calendar Control 12.0 Refuses Input

Tags: winforms, ms-access, vba, activex, ms-access-2007

In Microsoft Access, I have a series of forms that require the user to specify a date range.  Right now I do this with Calendar Control 12.0.  However, at random times, the control refuses to accept any user input (such as changing the date).

Why would the Calendar Control refuse input?  Is there any known workaround for this?

I'm running it on my development, which has the control properly registered.

Comment: Are you setting the control source or are you using code to save the date range?

Comment: I'm reading the `.Value` property of the form in code and leaving the control source empty.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to the control is a completely API generated Month Calendar derived directly from the Common Control DLL.   Another alternative is to use an Access form.   Which you can do anything with them you want.  There are also links to several downloadable calendar forms at my website.

See the [Calendar Tips](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/calendars.htm) page at my website  In addition there could, likely will, be lots of version problems when you go to distribute the MSCal.OCX.

Comment: The MSCal.ocx is already distributed, which was one of my major reasons for choosing it.  I'm using it on an Access form, and this is where the issue arises.

Comment: It's not always installed, and is one of the major components that can cause an app to break when it's installed on a different machine. There is no recovery from broken OCX's, unfortunately, so that's why I think it's a good idea to avoid them whenever possible, even when they are shipped with Office.

Answer (score 0):

The `Allow Edits` property needs to be set to `Yes` to make changes to the Calendar Control.  Somehow, this was set to `No` on the form with the control, so they would not respond to user input.

The other Data properties, such as `Allow Additions`, can be set to `No` on a dialog-style Access form.

Comment: But what is puzzling is why this happens "at random times" to quote your original posting.

Comment: Since the forms were largely similar, I did a Copy/Paste to duplicate them, and not all of the properties may have carried over correctly.